# How to implement SqlRetry Logic in Entity Framework 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to implement SqlRetry Logic in Entity Framework 6.0

Currently I am using this code:

```
public class MyConfiguration : DbConfiguration
{
    public MyConfiguration()
    {
       SetExecutionStrategy(SqlProviderServices.ProviderInvariantName, () => new SqlAzureExecutionStrategy(3,TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000)));                  
    }    
}
```

And Using this `DbConfigurationTypeAttribute` on context class. For example:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MyConfiguration))] 
public class MyContextContext : DbContext 
{ 
}
```

But, when I am debugging the code and giving the connection timeout=2(to check the retry logic), It is only trying once to connect with DB, but as per the code it should retry 3 time when its failing.

Please give any idea on this issue...